# How to create ec2 using javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// import AWS object without services
var AWS = require('aws-sdk/global');
var myCredentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({IdentityPoolId:'identitypool'});
var myConfig = new AWS.Config({
  credentials: myCredentials, region: 'us-west-2'
});
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-2a'});
var ec2 = new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15'});

 var params = {
  BlockDeviceMappings: [
     {
    DeviceName: "/dev/sdh", 
    Ebs: {
     VolumeSize: 100
    }
   }
  ], 
  ImageId: "ami-abc12345", 
  InstanceType: "t2.micro", 
  KeyName: "my-key-pair", 
  MaxCount: 1, 
  MinCount: 1, 
  SecurityGroupIds: [
     "sg-1a2b3c4d"
  ], 
  SubnetId: "subnet-6e7f829e", 
  TagSpecifications: [
     {
    ResourceType: "instance", 
    Tags: [
       {
      Key: "Purpose", 
      Value: "test"
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 };
 ec2.runInstances(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response
   /*
   data = {
   }
   */
     });
```

i m using this code to create instance in aws but its not working.I m not sure I am missing something If possible can anyone help me in step by step creation of ec2 using java script.As I am net to this

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to create IAM User that must have access to create ec2 instance in the region you want to create. Then you need to provide access key and secret key as:

```
var myConfig = new AWS.Config({
    accessKeyId:"access_key",
    secretAccessKey: "secret_key",
    region: "us-west-2"
});
```

Cognito Id credentials will not help you to create ec2 instance.

Comment: I have added this and removed the Cognito Id credentials  but now it says CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config undefined

Comment: Try replacing line var myConfig... with AWS.config.update({accessKeyId:"access_key",
    secretAccessKey: "secret_key",
    region: "us-west-2"})

Comment: thanks...it worked please could you explain why we have to update the config variable :)

Comment: Great if it works. Even I was unclear why we need to update it. Just found that solution at some discussion forum and asked you to check if it is working or not.